# How to speedup calling the interpolation function?

Tags: performance-tuning, fitting, interpolation, dataset, compile

Consider the following data:

```
dat={{0.00001, 7000.}, {0.0001, 7000.}, {0.001, 7000.}, {0.002, 
  6999.999999999987}, {0.0045000000000000005, 
  6999.999999999987}, {0.008, 6999.999999999987}, {0.02, 
  6999.999999999987}, {0.045, 6999.999999999987}, 
   {0.08, 4313.535758081632}, {0.15000000000000002, 
  3853.703772545988}, {0.30000000000000004, 3128.349789547097}, {0.5, 
  2800.9698445932686}, {0.7, 2437.7100097749117}, {0.9, 
  2363.8265106983717}, 
   {1.1, 2393.576853673258}, {1.2999999999999998, 
  2383.170945978633}, {1.4849999999999999, 2302.8502915536897}};
```

I would like to obtain the interpolation `int[x]` from this data and generate the table `{x, f[x]}` for x belonging to some dataset `xrand`. This is my code:

```
xrand=RandomReal[MinMax[dat[[All,1]]],10^6];
int[x_]=Interpolation[dat,InterpolationOrder->1][x];
finaldata=int[xrand];//AbsoluteTiming
```

However, it is slow:

> {1.04,Null}

The main problem is in the slow calling of `int`. In principle, instead of generating the interpolation, I may find a fit to `dat`, using e.g. `NonlinearModelFit`. However, if dealing with an arbitrary dataset, it would not be possible to make the procedure automatic since then one would need to change the fit function for `NonlinearModelFit`. Therefore, I am interested in a speedup of calling the interpolated function.

Is there any way to improve the performance?

Comment: 10^-6 s per value seems pretty good for software evaluation (select interpolant poly and then evaluate it). But I’m not sure what the real lower limit is.

Answer (score 1):

Try `purefunction`as Interpolation object

```
xrand = RandomReal[MinMax[dat[[All, 1]]], 10^6];

ip = Interpolation[dat, InterpolationOrder -> 1] ;
finaldata = ip[xrand]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{1.19475, Null}*)
```

which is much faster than your attempt

```
int[x_] = Interpolation[dat, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x];  
finaldata = int[xrand]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{1.49481, Null}*)
```

Comment: On my machine (Mathematica 12.1), both `ip[xrand]` and `int[xrand]` require 1 second.

Comment: What is your Mathematica version? Mine: v12.2 Windows11

Comment: Sorry, I have just updated my comment, it is 12.1@Windows 11.

Comment: Only if I  call `int` and `ip` multiple times (more than 1) I get the same execution times too!

Comment: I got ~1.03 s for `int` and 1.15 s for `ip` if launching them separately on a clean kernel.